# If $x_n\to x$, with $x_n=\frac{p_n}{q_n}$, and $x_n\ne x,n\in\Bbb{N}$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} q_n=\infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, irrational-numbers

Consider the function $$f(x)= \begin{cases}0&\text{if }x\in\Bbb{R}\setminus\Bbb{Q}~\text{or}~x=0\\\frac{1}{q}&\text{if }x=\frac{p}{q}, p\in\Bbb{Z},q\in\Bbb{N},(p,q)=1\end{cases}$$

Of course this function is discontinuous at rational numbers. To show it is continuous at irrational numbers I need:
If $x_n\to x$, with $x_n=\frac{p_n}{q_n}$, and $x_n\ne x,n\in\Bbb{N}$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} q_n=\infty$.

How to do that?

Comment: Since $q_n \geq 1$, this limes cannot be $0$. You mean $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} q_n = \infty$?

Comment: Sorry.. That was a typo. Edited it likewise. Obviously for continuity i need the limit to be $\infty$

Comment: You should also use the enviroment *cases*, as I have edited ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us assume that $(q_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ has a bounded subsequence - say w.l.o.g. that $(q_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is already bounded. Then we have
$$|q_n x - p_n | \longrightarrow 0.$$
So $(p_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is also bounded. Since both are integers, there exists a subsequence $(n_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $p_{n_k} = p$ and $q_{n_k} = q$. (We have only finite number of possible values, but infinity many elements.) Therefore, we find that
$$x= \frac{p}{q},$$
i.e. $x$ is rational.